# @ServerEndpoint and Spring MVC injection

Tags: java, spring-mvc, websocket

I am trying to inject annotated by @Repository class in @ServerEndpoint class. But when i am trying to call repository method it is return null. Another injected bean from this package is working fine.

```
@ApplicationScoped
@ServerEndpoint("/WebsocketHome/actions")
public class WebSocketServer {
private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(WebSocketServer.class);

@Inject
private SessionHandler sessionHandler;

@Inject
private PlaceRepository placeRepository;

@OnMessage
public void handleMessage(String message, Session session) {

    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

    try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) jsonParser.parse(message);

        if ("getRooms".equals(jsonObject.get("action"))) {
            List<Place> places = this.placeRepository.getAllPlaces(); //error is here               
        }
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            LOG.error(e.getMessage());
        }
.....
```

This is repository class:

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public class PlaceRepository {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<Place> getAllPlaces() {
        return this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from Place place").list();
    }
}
```

web.xml:

```
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
         http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
         version="3.0">
    <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/application-context.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

</web-app>
```

app-context.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:application.properties" system-properties-mode="ENVIRONMENT"/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.hms.repository"/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.hms.utils"/>
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager"/>

   <import resource="security-context.xml"/>

    <bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${db.driverClassName}" />
        <property name="url" value="${db.url}" />
        <property name="username" value="${db.username}" />
        <property name="password" value="${db.password}" />
        <!--
        <property name="initialSize" value="5" />
        <property name="maxActive" value="10" />
        <property name="maxIdle" value="5" />
        <property name="minIdle" value="2" />
        -->
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory"
          class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml"/>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${db.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hbm2ddl.auto">${db.hbm2ddl.auto}</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Error appears only on calling of @OnMessage method.
All junit @Tests of repository class returns fine results. 
What is wrong in my code?
Sorry for my english.

UPD:

It seems, that problem is in SessionFactory dependency because test method, that i add in @Repository:

```
public String testWS() {
        return "Test is ok!";
    }
```

returns fine result.

Comment: Could you provide your configuration as well? Initial thought is that the issue is with using Transactional annotation on your class. When you use @Transactional spring will provide a proxy and assuming you aren't using CGLIB the JDK dynamic proxy will not be compatible with with your concrete PlaceRepository

Comment: As you requested, i include config files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, looks like i found the right way. I found it in [Spring websocket documentation](https://spring.io/blog/2013/05/23/spring-framework-4-0-m1-websocket-support).
There are some steps what i did:

1. I put in type-level annotation:

   @ServerEndpoint(value = "/WebsocketHome/actions", configurator = SpringConfigurator.class)
2. I added @Service and @Controller to my websocket classes and "context:component-scan" path to my app-context.xml file so that Spring can find corresponding beans.
3. I added the "spring-websocket" dependency in my pom.xml (i use maven)

Maybe it is not the right way, but it is works fine for me.

Answer (score -1):

@Today jan 31' 2022 Just Add "spring-websocket" dependency

Comment: Skidus, this does not provide an answer to the question. You can [search for similar questions](/search), or refer to the related and linked questions on the right-hand side of the page to find an answer. If you have a related but different question, [ask a new question](/questions/ask), and include a link to this one to help provide context. See: [Ask questions, get answers, no distractions](/tour)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).